# How can I prevent my SSD to get full?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, storage, memory-management

When I built my PC, I bought a 128GB SSD (`C:/`) and a 1TB HD (`D:/`).

My only goal with the SSD was to install the OS, so that the PC would turn on faster, and everything else would be stored in HD. The theory looks nice but today my SSD went out of space.

I had already done some things: I had moved `Downloads` and `Desktop` to HD and always installed things in HD. I searched and found that the folder `AppData` (inside the SSD) was taking 50GB and other scattered folders were doing the rest of the job.

I will format my PC. My question is: what should I take to avoid this problem again?

Comment: 50GB in AppData definitely isn't normal. Look around and see what program(s) are eating up all that space.

Comment: I just found out Chrome's user data is taking 20GB.

Comment: Beyond simply getting a new SSD, it honestly sounds like you may need to investigate some utilities to help clean your SSD of extraneous files.

Comment: I'm sure one (or some) of your apps cause this problem. I have Windows 10, installed many apps on drive C and I update windows a lot because I'm in insider program. I use CCleaner free to cleanup junk files once every 1 or 2 months! Still only 58 GB used.

Comment: My main problem was Google Chrome User Data, it was taking 40GB+ only by itself. I moved it and it got better.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses the C: drive for many large folders and files, such WinSxS, User data, pagefile,sys swapfile.sys and hiberfil.sys. In addition, it is also the default drive for User and for Common Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, and Videos, and for *Program Files* and Program Files (x86).

Some of these can be changed by the user, and tools such as Nirsoft's [SpecialFoldersView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/special_folders_view.html) make this easier, but some system files are hard-coded to C:. Moving *some* of these designated folders can make the system unbootable, so make a backup image of both drives before making changes!

You're also faced with the issue that moving too many files onto the HDD will slow the system, not taking advantage of the SSD. If the system is constantly reading and writing to User AppData on HDD D:, there's little advantage to having a fast SSD.

Perhaps this is time to consider getting a larger SSD. 500 GB SSD's are available for US$50 on Amazon or Kingston.

Or try moving to a less storage-hungry OS such as Linux. My experience is that [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) *and included* browser, email application and LibreOffice suite, *and other utilities* such as image processing, *and associated data*, runs well on <<128 GB. This saves the HDD for large video files, a music collection or whatever.